# Adding and removing items in AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Looking to add some items, display a list then be able to delete each item separately, my understanding of this problem is that I have to create an array then update it each time I want to delete an item then save. That seems quite complex for a basic db operation, I tried several approachs don't know if my code is what I'm supposed to do. Can someone please point to the right direction?

The last error I'm facing:

> Object is null or undefined from
>       C:\Users\oled\stock\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\polyfills\Array.es6.js:24:26
>   _toConsumableArray

```
  FetchValue = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("Favorites").then((value) => {
      this.setState({
        favs: JSON.parse(value)
      });
    }).done();
  };

  SaveValue = () => {
    const newFavs = [...this.state.favs, this.state.UserInput];
    this.setState({ favs: newFavs, UserInput: '' }, () => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("Favorites", JSON.stringify(this.state.favs));
        Keyboard.dismiss()
    });
  };

  RemoveValue(item){
      const index = this.state.favs.indexOf(item);
      const newArray = [...this.state.favs];
      newArray.splice(index,1);
      this.setState({ favs: newArray });
      AsyncStorage.setItem("Favorites", JSON.stringify(newArray));
  }
```

Full code : https://pastebin.com/p7sbQTNG

Answer (score 0):

I think after removing last element, your array is empty. So after that whenever you try to remove the value from array it will give you the error. So please check the condition where array count is greater than 0 or not.

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: At the beginning I was able to save values, render on view then only last item of the array is removed, after that I changed the key and then the code breaks. I only changed the key. Now everytime I save something, it crash at saveValue function. If that makes sens please take a look at my full code, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

replace your **RemoveValue** method with this code.

We *need to check if the* **item** is not **null/undefined**

```
RemoveValue(item){
        if(item !== null &&  item !== undefined){
        const index = this.state.favs.indexOf(item);
        const newArray = [...this.state.favs];
        newArray.splice(index,1);
        this.setState({ favs: newArray });
        AsyncStorage.setItem("Favorites", JSON.stringify(newArray));
       }
```

***this will resolve your crash.***

Comment: The issue is save function